# Why UITransitionView / UIPopoverView / _UIPopoverStandartChromeView appears?

Tags: ios

Sometimes in our app a strange `UITransitionView` / `UIPopoverView` / `_UIPopoverStandartChromeView` appears, and it somehow trigger a button handler. But user does not touch that button, and this whole transition thing was not triggered at all. Do you have any idea? It is just over all the UIViews.

[image]